# Why Outputstream = new BufferedOutputStream not buffered?

Tags: java, io, buffer

From this [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)
I learn that

```
OutputStream out = = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
```

Is not buffered! Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "not buffered"? Your code uses to send information to file via buffer.

Comment: @LLAlive stream is not buffered...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misreading the documentation.

When the docs state:

> This stream is **not buffered**.

... they're referring to `FileOutputStream` itself, *not* the sample code.

Hence the next line in the docs:

> Most callers should wrap this stream with a `BufferedOutputStream`.